# PDO::FETCH_OBJ php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PDO::FETCH_OBJ -> Returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set.
For example:

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [email] => frank@frank.com [password] => password [salt] => salt [devices] => 1 [accounttype] => 1 [accountcreated] => 2014-03-26 [confirmed] => 1 [confirmcode] => 0 [logindate] => 2014-03-26 ) )
```

How do I get the email value??????? Below is what i have so far

```
  $_db = DB::getInstance();
  $_db = $_db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ', array($email, $pass));
  $results = $_db->results();
  print_r($results);
  print_r($results->email);  <<<<<<<<<<<--- does not work!
```

PLEASE HELP been at this for 24hours.... I know its simple because I have done it before... just cant seem to remember of find any referencing code!

Comment: It should be `$results[0]->email` or `foreach($results as $result) echo $result->email`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in what you pasted that $results is an array of objects, so you need to specify which item in the array to get a proper result for email.

Example:

```
print_r($results[0]->email);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like the following:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
        print_r($row->email);
}
```

If you expect to have just one row returned, it is always a good idea to check that. You can use count() with your $results variable like this:

```
if (count($results)==1) {
      print_r($results[0]->email);
}
```